# Put Xcode files into new folder. Since then, I encounter the following errors when building project in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

I encounter the following errors

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '- L/Users/andrecowardjr/Desktop/Parley/Parley/Google Analytics    

ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalytics

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Cant find out what the error is. Help needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into your project settings, check out the field 'Library Search Paths', and edit it so that it reflects where you moved your code/libraries. The error you're running into here is the linker can't find the Google Analytics library that your app is set up to link against (because you moved it).